# Automat a pivot table using python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to automate a pivot table and save it to an excel file using a python library that works on both windows and mac? I saw on many post that I could use pywin32 on windows but I'm not sure of what to use on mac. Also, Is it possible to automate something like in the following image. Below is my dummy data. nconv is renamed as Conversation

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at Pandas. It provides pivot table functionality and can write directly to Excel.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html,


https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: @RKReplogle Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, pandas pivot is static and not dynamic. It creates more of a regular table. I needed one that lets me specify the rows, columns, values and filters just like in excel, with drop downs for filter selections. `import win32com.client` does exactly what I want but I mostly need it for Mac. I saw that `xlwings` does in but I thinks it also uses win32com in the back(not too sure). But it's not working for me

Comment: There are a list of other functions to automate the pivot manipulations like pivot, melt, unstack, etc., which should provide all the functionality of Excel. It would be programatic as opposed to user selected drop downs, but I thought you wanted automated. 

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't properly stated. I've tried with panda and it's doesn't work as intended. Basically, I want to make a pivot table look like the second image I pasted above and pandas can't do that (from what I've seen and tried). When I save it to an excel sheet, it looks different and I'm not able to add filters either